# Related to regexp query

Tags: regex, elasticsearch

I am framing a query on attribute named distinguished name(dn)

Example: *"dn" : "cn=abc,ou=def,o=ig"*.

i am looking for query where dn ends with o=ig and has only one child for example

*"dn": "cn=abc,o=ig"*

*"dn": "cn=hgg,o=ig"*

*"dn": "ou=abc,o=ig"* and etc.

i tried this below query, can anyone figure out whats wrong in there.

```
{"track_total_hits":true,

    "_source": ["telephoneNumber", "mail", "ou", "givenName", "dn", "sn", "title", "modifyTimeStamp", "loginDisabled", "objectClass","cn"],

    "query":{
    "regexp":{
        "dn":{
            "value":"^[a-zA-Z0-9],o=ig$"
        }
    }
}

}
```

the mapping for dn,

```
"dn": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "not_standard",
                 "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    }
                }
            }
```

and analyzer

```
"not_standard": {
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "my_ascii_folding"
                    ],
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "standard"
                }
```

Comment: Try `"dn":{ "value":"[a-zA-Z0-9_]+=[^,]+,o=ig" }`

Comment: No it did not work,  i am supposed to use **dn.keyword** because standard analyzer removes = or any other special symbol.